# Calling a certain function based on a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to call certain functions based on a certain variable. If I have lots of functions based on this variable it quickly gets very ugly with all if statements. My questions is if there is a more elegant and "pythonic" solution than doing something like the code below?

```
if variable == 0:
    function_0()
elif variable == 1:
    function_1()
elif variable == 2:
    function_2()
```

Comment: Is the test always for equality? Do you need to test something like ``variable > 5``, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array of the functions, index with the variable and call the function.

```
[function_0, function_1, function_2][variable]()
```

Or do it via a dictionary

```
dd = {0 : function_0, 1 : function_1, 2 : function_2}
dd[variable]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary

```
fmap = {0: f1, 1: f2, 2: f3}
fmap[variable]()
```